How to add a non-chiral lepton doublet to the Standard Model?
How would the Standard Model Lagrangian (before symmetry breaking) change if we were to add a non-chiral lepton doublet $\ell_{L,R}$ with weak hypercharge $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ to the $SU(2)\times U(1)$ theory? Say, for instance,
$$\ell_L=\begin{pmatrix} N \\ E^- \end{pmatrix}_L, \ell_R=\begin{pmatrix} N \\ E^- \end{pmatrix}_R.$$
If we write the SM lagrangian as $\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{L}_{gauge}+\mathscr{L}_{fermion}+\mathscr{L}_{higgs}+\mathscr{L}_{yukawa}$, I believe the fermion sector shall change and talk to $\ell_L$ terms, although I'm not sure how specifically, nor do I know how the other sectors would change.

How do you propose to couple these L and R leptons to each other?

I'm not too sure since actively I'm learning particle physics, but I don't see why I can't come up with a new particle that mediates the interaction in the same way the W and Z bosons were postulated and later observed. (For reference this is problem 8.5 from Paul Langacker's The Standard Model and Beyond which I'm self studying from)
